# sorting a query result from DB by custom function

Tags: mysql, database, django, sorting

I want to return a sorted list from DB. The function that I want to use might look like

```
(field1_value * w1 + field2_value * w2) / ( 1 + currentTime-createTime(field3_value))
```

It is for `sort by popularity` feature of my application.

I wonder if how other people do this kind of sorting in DB(say MySQL)

I'm going to implement this in django eventually, but any comment on general direction/strategy to achieve this is most welcomed.

- Do I define a function and calculate score for rows for every
  requests?
- Do I set aside a field for this score and calculate score
  in a regular interval?
- Or using a time as a variable of the sorting
  function looks bad?
- How do other sites implement 'sort by popularity'?

I put the time variable because I wanted newer posts get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Do I define a function and calculate score for rows for every requests?

   You could do, but it's not necessary: you can simply provide that expression to your `ORDER BY` clause (the `1 + currentTime` part of the denominator doesn't affect the order of the results, so I have removed it):

   ```
   ORDER BY (field1 * w1 + field2 * w2) / UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field3) DESC
   ```

   Alternatively, if your query is selecting such a rating you can merely `ORDER BY` the aliased column name:

   ```
   ORDER BY rating
   ```
2. > Do I set aside a field for this score and calculate score in a regular interval?

   I don't know why you would need to calculate at a regular interval (as mentioned above, the constant part of the denominator has no effect on the *order* of results)—but if you were to store the result of the above expression in its own field, then performing the `ORDER BY` operation would be very much faster (especially if that new field were suitably indexed).

Comment: thanks for response!  I wanted to ask if any of the two strategies are preferred over the other.  calculating score for every request vs calculating score in batch... In any way, I fear it'd be slow as the table gets more and more rows.  In short, what's the good strategy to apply the sorting which can scale?

Comment: @Eugene: See my answer to #2, above.

Comment: is #1 feasible for a table that's expected to grow?